# Product of two abelian subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A theorem of Ito says that if $G=AB$ where $A,B$ are abelian subgroups of $G$ then $G'$ is abelian.

It was an exercise in a book, to prove, *without using above fact*, that

> If $G$ is finite group and $G=AB$ where $A,B$ are abelian subgroups then $G$ is solvable.

Can you give a hint for this?

Comment: It would be enough to show that one of the subgroups normalizes the other, but I am also not sure how to show this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, Ito gave a direct proof by a surprisingly short computation, which shows directly that $G$ is $2$-step solvable. So we need not use the fact that $G'$ is abelian, but rather we can just take Ito's computation.

*Proposition (N. Ito 1955)*: Let $G=AB$ the product of two abelian subgroups
$A$ and $B$, then $G$ is metabelian, i.e., solvable of class $\le 2$.

Proof: see B.A., S.Franciosi, F. de Giovanni, "Products of groups", Oxford
University Press (1992). There is also [Ito's original article](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002385163&IDDOC=158722), but it is in German. Nevertheless one can see the short computation.

Note that the proof actually does not need $G$ to be finite.